# Procesar un fichero .csv en java

Tags: java, java-util-scanner, archivo

Estoy intentando leer un archivo excell para crear un archivo sin formato de texto con sus datos. Me da un error tipo errorjava.util.InputMismatchException, pero no muestra ningun tipo de ruta de locaclizacion del fallo. Creo que es por el modo de cómo trato de invocar los metodos que ofrece Scanner, pero estoy atascado.
El código Java es el siguiente

```
private static void procesaFichero(String filename) throws IOException{
        Scanner is = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filename));
        VectorDinamicoRegistro vPM10 = new VectorDinamicoRegistro();
        VectorDinamicoRegistro vPM25 = new VectorDinamicoRegistro();
        VectorDinamicoRegistro vNO2 = new VectorDinamicoRegistro();
        Formatter dos = new Formatter("RegistroContaminantes.txt");
        Registro r = null;

        is.useDelimiter("; , |\r\n");
        // Primero lee la cabecera
        String c1 = is.next();
        String c2 = is.next();
        String c3 = is.next();
        String c4 = is.next();
        String c5 = is.next();

        // Y la escribe en RegistroCampus.txt
        dos.format("%2s%2s%3s%3s%3s\n", c1, c2, c3, c4, c5);
        while (is.hasNext()) {
            // Lee cada linea de texto en un Registro
            r = new Registro(); // cada vez un registro distinto!!
            r.setFechayHora(is.next());
            r.setZona(is.next());
            r.setPM10(is.nextInt());
            r.setPM25(is.nextInt());
            r.setNO2(is.nextInt());
            // Y añade el registro al vector
            vPM10.add(r);
            vPM25.add(r);
            vNO2.add(r);
            // Escribe la linea en RegistroCampus.txt
            dos.format("%24s%20s%22d%17.2f\n", r.getFechayHora(), r.getZona(), r.getPM10(), r.getPM25(), r.getNO2());
        }
        is.close();
        dos.close();
}
```

Y en cuanto al archivo .csv

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tiene un formato parecido al siguiente:

```
Fecha;Zona;PM10,PM25,NO2 
2018-11-01 01:00h;CONSTITUCION;9,6,19 
2018-11-02 01:00h;CONSTITUCION;17,7,35
```

Comment: Agrega el stacktrace de la excepción que te dá, y marca en el código cuál es la línea donde ocurre la excepción.

Comment: Es que dice que no la encuentra... por eso mismo no se donde esta el error.

Answer (score 0):

Sin demasiada información, pero lo he ejecutado en mi entorno, y el problema parece estar en tu regex. No sé exáctamente cuáles son tus posibles separadores, pero tu regex toma como separador todos esos caracteres juntos. Para que matchee uno de los caracteres, tienes que ponerlo entre corchetes:

`is.useDelimiter("[;,\\n]");`
Este me funcionó a mi con tu ejemplo de archivo, usa punto y coma, coma, y salto de línea como separadores, y obtuve esto:

```
C1:Fecha, C2:Zona, C3:PM10, C4:PM25, C5:NO2
C1:2018-11-01 01:00h, C2:CONSTITUCION, C3:9, C4:6, C5:19
C1:2018-11-02 01:00h, C2:CONSTITUCION, C3:17, C4:7, C5:35
```